# Is there is a difference in time and space complexicity between equalization sign and initialisation?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

For example i have the following code:

```
int value = 10;
int firstMethod = value;
int secondMethod (value);
```

What is the difference in time and space if I use second method? Is it gonna take longer? Is there any reason why people write code with first method?

Comment: These are the same. Both initialize.

Comment: I know they both initialize, my question is about time, does it take longer to use second method?

Comment: Firstly, probably compiler-dependant. Secondly, this is likely a premature optimization. Thirdly, measure it yourself with `chrono::steady_clock` (you'll find no difference)

Comment: "Is there any reason why people write code with first method?" - most people find it clearer. The third looks somewhat like either a function call or a function declaration.

Comment: The standard explicitly says "The form of initialization (using parentheses or `=`) is generally insignificant" (although, it "does matter when the initializer or the entity being initialized has a class type").

Comment: " Is it gonna take longer?" I wonder how you are going to measure that.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear. I would be surprised if a compiler generated different code for either case.

Comment: Look at the generated assembly code.  It should be identical.

Comment: I'm curious _why_ you came up with this question. What additional work or memory requirements do you envisage?

Answer (score 2):

No.

The difference here is in syntax only.

The lines represent exactly the same program behaviour.

Note that for more complex types, the two forms of initialisation may mean different things.

FWIW, I still use the first syntax for primitives because, I dunno, I just do. It's personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in speed when initializing built-in types using [direct](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) or [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization).